# Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 34: Connection closed at byte 2359280. Expected 53812451 bytes

Tags: java, android, sdk, ioexception

Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-34_r01.zip
java.io.IOException: Connection closed at byte 2359280. Expected 53812451 bytes.
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 34: Connection closed at byte 2359280. Expected 53812451 bytes..
"Install Sources for Android 34 (revision 1)" failed.

why this is happening ?

my firewall is off.

please provide me a clear solution because i re run this download ,it is not working.
i change sdk location still not working. off the firewall still not working.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: this could be related to a time limit on the file server - it just kicks you out if the download traffic stalls e.g. due a bad connection